# Splash screen not coming

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am writing an application starting with Silverlight+XNA Template in Windows phone.
I have an image named "Splashscreenimage.jpg" in my project root folder. But the splash screen is not coming. What may be the reason?

Comment: give some codes you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set this image as Content in Build Action property? Recall, the size should be 480X800

Regards,

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769511%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

josemiguel

Answer (score 0):

try splashscreenimage.jpg and check Build Action